# Cross compiling glib with custom gettext

Tags: cross-compiling, gettext, glib

I'm trying to croos compile glib library and and I think I need the gettext library as well.

This is the ./configure output

./configure --host=i686-linux --enable-libmount=no --with-pcre=internal --prefix=/home/glib/xport/
    ...
    ...
    checking for LIBFFI... yes
    checking locale.h usability... no
    checking locale.h presence... yes
    configure: WARNING: locale.h: present but cannot be compiled

```
configure: WARNING: locale.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?

configure: WARNING: locale.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: locale.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: locale.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------------------------------- ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=glib ##
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------------------------------- ##
checking for locale.h... no
checking for CFPreferencesCopyAppValue... no
checking for CFLocaleCopyCurrent... no
checking libintl.h usability... no
checking libintl.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: libintl.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: libintl.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: libintl.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: libintl.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: libintl.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------------------------------- ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to http://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=glib ##
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------------------------------------- ##
checking for libintl.h... no
configure: error: 
*** You must have either have gettext support in your C library, or use the
*** GNU gettext library. (http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html)


Make fails with the following:
ls: cannot access msgunfmt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access gettext: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access hostname: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libgnu.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msgexec: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access recode-sr-latin: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msgmerge: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/libffi.so.6.0.1: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msggrep: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access xgettext: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access envsubst: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msgconv: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msgmerge: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libcroco_rpl.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msgattrib: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libtextstyle.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access hello: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libxml_rpl.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libffi_convenience.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libglib_rpl.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libgettextpo.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msgattrib: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libgnuintl.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msgcmp: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msgen: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/test-localcharset: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access cldr-plurals: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libgettextlib.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libffi.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msgen: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/libgettextlib-0.20.1.so: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/hostname: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/recode-sr-latin: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/libgettextpo.so.0.5.5: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msgfmt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msggrep: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msguniq: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msginit: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/libgettextsrc-0.20.1.so: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msgfilter: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msguniq: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/libgnuintl.so.8.1.6: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/urlget: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msgcat: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msginit: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/libasprintf.so.0.0.0: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msgcmp: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msgfmt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/hello: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msgconv: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access urlget: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libgettextsrc.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access ngettext: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access libasprintf.la: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msgunfmt: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access test-localcharset: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/libtextstyle.so.0.0.0: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/xgettext: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msgcomm: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msgcat: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access msgfilter: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/cldr-plurals: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msgcomm: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access .libs/msgexec: No such file or directory
```

These files are available in my custom gettext directory that was previously compiled.
How should I link the two ?
Thank !

Comment: Did you check `config.log` for the exact error? Your `configure` output suggests that `libintl.h` was found but does not compile. The reason for that will be in `config.log`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Set the following environment variables:

```
CFLAGS=-I<directory where gettext headers are>
CPPFLAGS=-I<directory where gettext headers are>
CXXFLAGS=-I<directory where gettext headers are>
LDFLAGS=-L<directory where gettext libraries are>
```

and make them available to configure & make:  either export them in the shell/script or specify them when invoking configure & make (ex. `CFLAGS=-I... CPPFLAGS=-I...  ...  ./configure --prefix=... ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a recent (supported) version of GLib and build using Meson, rather than autotools. It has [better/easier cross-compilation support](https://mesonbuild.com/Cross-compilation.html) than autotools.

All versions of GLib which are built using autotools are no longer supported, and will no longer receive security updates. They are too old.